# SSRS : table design

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How do i fill the table line although it has no data to display? 
I had make the pagebreak after each group is finished. How could I achieve like this? Any help is much appreciated.[[image]]

right now what i am getting is just like figure(2) [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a new row (or rows) below your total row outside your group and leave it blank.

**Right-click** on your **total** row and **Insert Row** --> **Below** (**Outside Group - Below** if your total is part of some grouping).

[image]